# How to customise Firebase in-app messages?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am using the *image only* message layout, attaching the screenshot of the current implementation.

[image: firebase-in-app-message]
I need this image dialog to be filled the whole screen. Is there any configuration or customisation can be done to achieve it? Or what are the possible customisation to this dialog?

Also, Can we able to set font for top banner or modal message layout text?

Comment: Hi!!. Did you found how to customize? I don´t found documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the Firebase In-App Messaging display SDK for Android to customize how In-App Messaging displays in our messages

Details : https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/customize-messages.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about how do you do it? Where do you start?

Comment: Any details to customize the In-App messaging? Can I show a popup with two button and the header title and subtitle for the popup and show for Firebase In-app messaging in ios